# Regex grepl for specific and repeating pattern

Tags: r, regex, repeat, grepl

To match strings of the format "lkas32kj_123_3.21" I use (in R)

`grepl("^[[:alnum:]]+_[[:digit:]]+_[[:digit:]]+\\.{0,1}[[:digit:]]+$", "lkas32kj_123_3.21")`

How can I extend this to cases with `|` repeating/compound strings of **any length** such as (length  three) "lkas32kj_123_3.21|l3kj_12_0.21|123e_4_32.1".

Is there a way to make a nested (recursive ?) pattern ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
"^[[:alnum:]]+(?:_\\d+){2}(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:\\|[[:alnum:]]+(?:_\\d+){2}(?:\\.\\d+)?)*$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eriQ2k/1)

In R, use

```
x <- c("lkas32kj_123_3.21", "lkas32kj_123_3.21|l3kj_12_0.21|123e_4_32.1", "+++NO+++")
rx <- "[[:alnum:]]+(?:_\\d+){2}(?:\\.\\d+)?"
grepl(paste0("^", rx, "(?:\\|", rx ,")*$"), x)
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/LxitNm).

The pattern is like this: `^{single_item_regex}(?:\|{single_item_regex})*$`. It matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `{single_item_regex}` - the pattern you have for the single item (note I replaced `[[:digit:]]` with `\d` to make it shorter, but if you need to stick to the POSIX character class, you may)
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\|` - a pipe
  - `{single_item_regex}` - the single item pattern
- `)*` - end of group, repeat 0 or more times
- `$`  - end of string.

In the single item pattern, I suggest replacing `\.{0,1}\d+` with `(?:\.\d+)?` as the intention here is to match an optional `.` and 1+ digits at the end.

Comment: Ah - could you break it up. The `?:_` is forward/back references ?

Comment: @user3375672 Please check the update and let me know if there is anything unclear.

Comment: Nice man! Great explanation - the  `(?:\|{single_item_regex})*` is intuitive.